# Project Euler #2 For Large Limits

Tags: haskell

I have a Haskell solution to [Project Euler Problem 2](http://projecteuler.net/problem=2) which works fine for the four million limit, as well as for limits up to 10^100000, taking only a few seconds on my machine.

But for anything bigger, e.g. 10^1000000, the computation does not return in good time, if at all (have tried leaving it for a couple of minutes). What is the limiting factor here?

```
evenFibonacciSum :: Integer -> Integer
evenFibonacciSum limit = 
  foldl' (\t (_,b) -> t + b) 0 . takeWhile ((<=limit) . snd) . iterate doIteration $ (1,2) where
    doIteration (a, b) = (twoAB - a, twoAB + b) where
      twoAB = 2*(a + b)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you are summing the (even) Fibonacci numbers. That means you have to calculate them all. But

```
F(n) ≈ φ^n / √5, with  φ = (1 + √5)/2
```

So you are adding a lot of numbers of large size, `Θ(n)` bits for `F(n)`. For a limit of `10^1000000`, you need about 800000×2 additions of numbers larger than `10^500000`. In general, you need `Θ(n)` additions of numbers with `Θ(n)` bits.

Adding numbers of `d` digits [in whatever base] is an `O(d)` operation. So your algorithm is quadratic in the exponent.

To avoid that, find a closed formula for the sum `S(k)` of the first `k` even Fibonacci numbers (hint: it's a relatively easy formula involving *one* Fibonacci number), find the largest `k` so that `F(3*k) <= limit`, and compute the sum using the formula and the algorithm to compute `F(n)` in `O(log n)` steps e.g. [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/arithmoi/0.4.0.3/doc/html/Math-NumberTheory-Lucas.html#v%3afibonacci).

Answer (score 0):

The problem here seems that you're using a formula for the even fibonacci-numbers that takes linear time to be computed. IIf you double your limit, your computation time also doubles. There should be an algorithm that takes only logarithmic time (if you double the limit, the time changes by a constant value), but it's your job to find out. I'm not spoiling Euler answers here.

Comment: Given that his code already works perfectly fine for the four million limit given by the Project Euler problem, I wouldn't consider providing a solution for (much) higher limits a spoiler.

Comment: @sepp2k also true. There should be a simple solution, I just have to research a little bit...